# android:fontFamily Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

**Код**

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
```

**Ошибка**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что за ошибка и как её устранить?

Comment: Текст ошибки читал? Что за ошибка написано в самой первой строчке. Как ее устранить следует оттуда же.

Comment: Не очень хорошо владею английским языком. С какими проблемами я столкнусь, если не исправлю эту ошибку?

Comment: Потому что на более современных устройствах шрифт работает без ошибок

Comment: Грозит тем, что не скомпилируется.

Comment: Файл компилируется. Но ошибка в файле подсвечивается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно изменить минимальную версию SDK (`minSdkVersion`) на 16. Приложения с версией СДК 15 и ранее не будут поддерживаться, но т.к. это Андроид 4.0.3 и ранее, то и не страшно.

Конечно, можно сделать стили/правила компиляции и для таких ранних версий андроида, но для таких старых версий это вряд ли оправдано.